# Debugging map reduce: Break points on mapper is not hitting

Tags: hadoop

I am trying to debug mapper in eclipse.

```
   I set my config to run in local by adding below code in driver class

        conf.set("mapred.job.tracker", "local");
        conf.set("fs.default.name", "local");
```

Breakpoint at driver class hits, but it doesn't hit break point in mapper. Can any one help me in this topic?

---

Trying to debug default WordCount program. It seems Mapper is not running at all. It is giving below exception.

"java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/yarn/exceptions/YarnException
 at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.YarnClientProtocolProvider.create"

I also added respective jar file (hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-2.3.0.jar). Still is throwing exception.

Thank you.

Comment: Please post your mapper code.  It's possible that you didn't properly override the map() method and it isn't being called at all.

Comment: You set the properties correctly. Please put print statement in the Mapper to see if that code is even being run at all.

Comment: I checked it, Mapper is not running at all. I am getting class not found exception at YarnClientProtocolProvider.create. (I added the corresponding jar file). still doesn't work.